# Binding Height of RectangleGeometry

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a Border with a clipping mask as a RectangleGeometry added in a ResourceDictionary. I want the RectangleGeometry rectangle to change its Height depending on a value from code behind but don't know how to bind just the height.

The Border with the clip:

```
<Border Width="50" Height="50" Background="#F0F1F3" CornerRadius="4">
    <Border.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0, 0, 50, 10" />
    </Border.Clip>
</Border>
```

I found some answer to a similar question here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7c7dbdc9-3fdb-4893-ab1f-082df9594f25/rectanglegeometry-binding?forum=wpf
And tried to do the same thing - add multibinding properties, but don't know what to do with these now:

```
<RectangleGeometry.Rect>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Converter}">
        <Binding ElementName="mainGrid" Path="Width"/>
        <Binding ElementName="mainGrid" Path="Height"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</RectangleGeometry.Rect>
```

How to define the origin point here? How to provide the Width and Height values? And what do I put in the ElementName?

Comment: The MultiBinding Converter's Convert method would return a Rect from whatever values the input bindings produce. If you want to bind to just a single value, you wouldn't even need a MultiBinding. The Converter of a regular Binding could convert the source value into an appropriate Rect.

Comment: How is the "value from code behind" defined?

Comment: public int DownloadProgressAsImageHeight
        {
            // Convert percentage to image height points inside the display box
            get { return (int)((DownloadProgress / 100) * _iconBoxHeight); }
        }

Comment: Why don't you simply set the Rect property in the code-behind when your property is updated? Do you know how to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

Comment: I know the theory but wouldn't know how to implement it in this specific case

Comment: And the answer to my first question is...?

Comment: it's in my first comment

Comment: No, it's not. Set the Rect when you set the DownloadProgress property and you should be all set.

Comment: How do I set the Rect in code-behind?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you might as well set the `Rect` property of the `RectangleGeometry` whenever you set the `DownloadProgress` property. Give the `RectangleGeometry` an `x:Name` in your XAML markup:

```
<Border Width="50" Height="50" Background="#F0F1F3" CornerRadius="4">
    <Border.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry x:Name="rect" />
    </Border.Clip>
</Border>
```

...and set its `Rect` property right after you have set the `DownloadProgress` property:

```
DownloadProgress = 10;
rect.Rect = new Rect(0, 0, 50, (double)DownloadProgressAsImageHeight);
```

Comment: Damn, the code-behind does not recognize the `rect` object, probably because I've created it in a resource dictionary, not directly in the `.xaml` file. Is there a way to tell the code-behind how to find the object?

Comment: Why did you define a Border as a resource...?

Comment: It's inside a DataTemplate which is inside the resource dictionary and I have to add my code in it

Comment: Well, it might had been an idea to clarify this in your question...how to get a reference to the RectangleGeometry depends on where it is defined of course.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that. XAML is still a huge mystery for me. I wish I'd only had to work with pure C# (WinForms/GTK#) but I can't choose myself unfotunately.

Comment: You're probably better of binding it to your property. But then you must implement the INPC interface and use a converter to convert the int value to a Rect.

Comment: For what? The entire thing? SO is not for anyone else to write code for you. Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: I'm trying to use a converter with multibinding now (to pass width and height to it):
https://paste.ofcode.org/t5irkRWFypBqMQuBT57Cuy